# Login to mediawiki by api on wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, class, mediawiki, webrequest

I am trying to create an app for wp7 to login to wikipedia and help with translating the pages.
I am stuck right at the beginning since I can't get it to login through the mediawiki API.
The relevant part of the code goes like this:

```
        data.Append("action=login&lgname" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textBox1.Text));
        data.Append("&lgpassword=" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode(passwordBox1.Password));

        request.BeginGetRequestStream(new AsyncCallback(GetRequestStreamCallback),request);
        request.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(GetResponseCallback), request);

        public void GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
           Stream postStream = request.EndGetRequestStream(asynchronousResult);
           byte[] byteData = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data.ToString());
           postStream.Write(byteData, 0, data.Length);
           postStream.Close();
        }
        private static void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
           HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;

           HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
           Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream();
           StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
           string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

           streamResponse.Close();
           streamRead.Close();

           response.Close();
    }
```

The problems are:

On the GetRequestStreamCallback I can't pass the data string from the main function. How do I do this?

On the GetResponseCallback function how do I return the responsestring String so that I can output later?

Answer (score 0):

What you're actually trying to do is two asynchronous operations, one after another - it's worth remembering that the `BeginXxx` methods return before they've finished - so in your case, you ask for the request stream to write to, and immediately ask for the response, so bad things will ensue.

It's possibly worth looking at other examples, such as those in [opensource code](http://localangle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/16988#210860) - you'll see that you don't typically call `BeginGetResponse` until you've finished writing to the stream returned by `EndGetRequestStream`

Comment: My code here is similar to the one given on the msdn documentation for the begin methods. Is it possible to change the begin methods for the get methods? Silverlight doesn't seem recognize them.

Comment: Nevermind. I'll do this another way. Check api.php?action=query&format=xml&meta=userinfo and if id = "0" open web browser in the app with the login page loaded. If id is something else, then move forward. I'll probably have to learn the begin methods later on anyway.